# Why did one of my GKE LoadBalancer services stop being accessible after recreating the cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have two LoadBalancer services in a GKE cluster. One of these is accessible via its external load balancer IP, but not the other. They were both accessible before the cluster was deleted and recreated. This was done using Terraform, so the clusters should be identical (and I cannot see anything different about them). The cluster was re-populated using the same K8s object configurations (the same Kustomize directory).

Service that works:

```
Name:                     v2alpha-public-api-server
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=kingdom
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=v2alpha-public-api-server
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=halo-cmms
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/app-protocols: {"grpc-port": "HTTP2"}
                          cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
                          kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
                          system: kingdom
Selector:                 app=v2alpha-public-api-server-app
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.92.11.149
IPs:                      10.92.11.149
IP:                       34.123.211.251
LoadBalancer Ingress:     34.123.211.251
Port:                     grpc-port  8443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 grpc-port  31562/TCP
Endpoints:                10.88.1.3:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none
```

Service that doesn't:

```
Name:                     system-api-server
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=kingdom
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=system-api-server
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=halo-cmms
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/app-protocols: {"grpc-port": "HTTP2"}
                          cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
                          kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
                          system: kingdom
Selector:                 app=system-api-server-app
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.92.1.31
IPs:                      10.92.1.31
IP:                       34.69.224.217
LoadBalancer Ingress:     34.69.224.217
Port:                     grpc-port  8443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 grpc-port  32064/TCP
Endpoints:                10.88.1.2:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

The cluster is VPC-native, public, and zonal. I can access the service using port forwarding, so I know the underlying Deployment is functioning correctly. The cluster has network policies enabled to restrict traffic, but deleting those has no effect. Furthermore, I enabled network policy logging to ensure that the policies were being applied properly (the connections were being allowed by the  policies). I also enabled firewall logging and confirmed that the connections are being allowed by firewall rules.

The simple test is using `grpc_health_probe`. The failing service gets `timeout: failed to connect service`. Increasing the connection timeout doesn't help. The working service gets a response.

Comment: I think I figured out the cause. At some point in the past, I had configured the service as using an internal load balancer. That may have been sticky.

Comment: If you were able to figure out the solution to your question, kindly post it as answer so others can see it too

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm the cause nor actually fix the issue. I ended up working around the issue by setting up an internal load balancer again since everything I needed to access it from was in the same VPC network. Indeed, the external load balancer service is still timing out when I try to test it using grpc_health_probe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there's no issue, and there were two problems on my end that made me think there was one:

1. There were some outdated `hostAliases` in the Deployments from other clusters that were calling this service. The merge behavior when running `kubectl apply` for this is additive, so they hadn't been cleared out.
2. The TLS certificate of the host didn't match the address I was connecting from. `grpc_health_probe` doesn't indicate TLS errors of this type, and instead just times out.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Sanjay Vasandani:

I think I figured out the cause. At some point in the past, I had configured the service as using an internal load balancer. That may have been sticky.

Feel free to update this answer for improvement